# How to drop all MySQL tables from the command-line?

Tags: command-line, terminal, mysql

Usually I open Terminal.app and connect to a remote MySQL database.

Then I use this command to drop a table:

```
mysql> drop table [table name];
```

But what I need is the command line to drop all tables in the database.

If I use:

```
mysql> drop database [database name];
```

I'll destroy the database completely and I won't be able to create tables again. Am I right?

Comment: [MySQL Empty Database / Delete or Drop All Tables](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-empty-mysql-database/), [MySQL - Drop all Tables in a Database Using a Single Command Line Command](http://knaddison.com/technology/mysql-drop-all-tables-database-using-single-command-line-command), [Drop all tables from a MySQL Database without deletion](http://edwardawebb.com/linux/drop-tables-mysql-database-deletion), ...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can drop the database then immediately recreate it:

> `mysql> drop database [database name];`
>   `mysql> create database [database name];`

[Or you could use a script to drop each table in the database.](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-empty-mysql-database/)

Comment: ok, just to be sure: I connect to remote database in Terminal with this line: **/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql -h 80.54.554.10 -u adm_user -p my_db**.    After dropping and creating the database as you said will I need to change this connection values or they remain the same?

Comment: @chef - Dropping all tables and dropping the whole database does not have the same effect. If you drop only the tables any database wide permissions will remain, not so if you drop/recreate the database.

Comment: @chefnelone : Be careful !!! Dropping a database drops stored procedures and user-defined views as well.

Comment: Quite clear for me. I'll go with the script to delete each table.

Comment: it's totally unsafe, see the comments [http://stackoverflow.com/a/12403742/1713660](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12403742/1713660)

Answer (score 13):

You can try the following command:

```
mysqldump --no-data --add-drop-table DB_NAME | grep ^DROP | mysql -v DB_NAME
```

Or:

```
mysql --silent --skip-column-names -e "SHOW TABLES" DB_NAME | xargs -L1 -I% echo 'DROP TABLE `%`;' | mysql -v DB_NAME
```

Where `DB_NAME` is your database name. Database credentials you can specify either in `~/.my.cnf` or adding them to the command (e.g. `-uroot -proot`).

This method has some advantages over dropping and creating the database in case your database user doesn't have permission to drop it.

Comment: Confirmed second example, awesome.  Add db credentials as additional flags before `--silent` and `-v` / `--verbose` respectively like: `--user=username --password=password --host=host.name`

Comment: Good idea. But have some problem when there is FOREIGN KEY. I add `| sort -r` to reverse line, but still not compatible some db.

Comment: Thanks for the second example. I also needed to deactivate foreign key check before dropping tables: `mysql --silent --skip-column-names -e "SHOW TABLES" DB_NAME | xargs -L1 -I% echo 'DROP TABLE \`%\`;' | mysql --init-command="SET SESSION FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;" -v DB_NAME`

Comment: Thanks for the second example, it is exactly what I need to delete my tables !

Answer (score 2):

`mysql -u USERHERE -pPASSWORDHERE --silent --skip-column-names -e "SHOW TABLES" DATABASENAMEHERE | xargs -L1 -I% echo 'SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0; DROP TABLE`%`; SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;' | mysql -u USERHERE -pPASSWORDHERE -v DATABASENAMEHERE`

Comment: Welcome to Super User!  While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could explain *why* it does so.  We’re looking for comprehensive, high-quality answers that provide some explanation and context.  Don’t just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations.  Answers that don’t include explanations may be removed.  Also, check your formatting.

Comment: Not forget set foreign_key_checks = 1  after drop tables: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/2873991/4306855

mysql -u USERHERE -pPASSWORDHERE --silent --skip-column-names -e "SHOW TABLES" DATABASENAMEHERE | xargs -L1 -I% echo 'SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0; DROP TABLE%;SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;' | mysql -u USERHERE -pPASSWORDHERE -v DATABASENAMEHERE